# Toggling the aria-expanded element to true on page load

Tags: javascript, html, overriding, wai-aria

all.

I'm no programmer (and don't have access to one) and have been asked to automatically expand an aria control on a webpage.

We have very little control over the code (just basic javascript and css) as it's hosted by Okta, and all the examples I've looked at here are baffling to me. Here's what the source for the section looks like:

```
<a href="#" data-se="needhelp" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="help-links-container" class="link help js-help">
 Bunch of text here that contains a list.
</a>
```

How I can expand the aria on page load.

Comment: When you say the answers below didn't work, do you mean that the value of the attribute didn't change, or that item that clicking the link opens didn't open? Because changing the aria attribute itself doesn't open/close things. The [aria-expanded attribute](https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/sensible-aria-usage/expanded/) is so screen readers can announce whether something is open or closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("link help js-help").setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
```

Comment: Adding this to a new script section where Okta tells you to didn't affect the collapsed help text, and adding it in the predefined section where Okta has their scripts broke the login widget completely. Here's what they give you to work with:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="robots" content="none" />
    <title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
    {{{SignInWidgetResources}}}
  </head><body>
    <div class="login-bg-image" style="background-image: {{bgImageUrl}}"></div>
    <div id="okta-login-container"></div>

Comment: <!--
        "OktaUtil" defines a global OktaUtil object
        that contains methods used to complete the Okta login flow.
     -->
    {{{OktaUtil}}} <div id="auth-footer"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // "config" object contains default widget configuration
        // with any custom overrides defined in your admin settings.
        var config = OktaUtil.getSignInWidgetConfig();

Comment: // Render the Okta Sign-In Widget
        var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn(config);
        oktaSignIn.renderEl({ el: '#okta-login-container' },
            OktaUtil.completeLogin,
            function(error) {
                // Logs errors that occur when configuring the widget.
                // Remove or replace this with your own custom error handler.
                console.log(error.message, error);
            }
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

1. you can give your "a" tag an id, for example, I gave it an id called "link-list"
2. when page load, you can use "document.getElementById("link-list")", then you can access "a" tag
3. use "setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true")" to change aria-expanded attribute to false

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a
      id="link-list"
      href="#"
      data-se="needhelp"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="help-links-container"
      class="link help js-help"
      >Bunch of text here that contains a list.</a
    >
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
        var linkList = document.getElementById("link-list");
        linkList.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update step 3 to say "true" at the end?  You're changing the value to "true", not "false".

Comment: Unfortunately, adding this didn't work. It looks like we'd need to host our own sign in page. Thanks for trying! :-)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the only way I actually saw that aria section was after the page loads. It's not exposed in the simple HTML editor that they give you.